# Create batch script that reads multiple input parameters form source file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to write a batch script that copies files of one folder to other folder. User will provide source and destination folders in a file. This file may be xml or cinfig or text file. The file has multiple values.

For instance the text file may have

```
<key="1" source="D:\test\" destination="E:\folderfile\"/>
<key="2" source="E:\test\" destination="F:\folderfile\"/>
<key="3" source="C:\test\" destination="D:\folderfile\"/>
<key="4" source="D:\test\" destination="E:\folderfile\"/>
<key="5" source="D:\test\" destination="E:\folderfile\"/>
```

when batch file is run, it asks user to input key values. Let say if user provided 2,4,5 values, the batch script should get source & destination of key 2 from file and copy the files and so on it should perform for 4 and 5 keys also.

Please don't suggest to use power-shell script or vb script as i am supposed to do in batch script only. 
Anyone help could be appreciated.

Thanks
Praveen

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far that isn't working? This is not a "do my assignment for me" site; you need to show that you've put some effort into solving it yourself. Post your efforts, and we'll try and help you figure out why they're not working.

Comment: Hello Ken, actually am 1 day old to batch scripting. I have copied files using copy & xcopy command, but am not sure how to get multiple input values form other source files. Let say if user prompted to provide keys, based on provided keys the batch script has to get source & destination paths from other file(txt or xml files).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to format your files as simple commands:

```
copy d:\test\ e:\folderfile\
copy e:\test\ f:\folderfile\
...
```

You could use the following batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n . %1^|find "%2:"') do (
set searchtext = "%2:"
set linetext=%%a
set commandToCall=!linetext:%2:=!
)
call %commandToCall%
```

Using:

```
mybatchfile.bat input.txt <linenumber>
```

Comment: @Praveen Do you have an input file called input.txt sitting in the same folder as the batch script?

Comment: Hi Shimoon, Thanks for your reply. But the one you sent was not working. Getting error like "FINDSTR: Cannot open input.txt" & here in the code you specifed line number as one the input for batch file, but i want the key values to be specified as input. Let say like mybatchfile.bat 2,3,4. Here 2,3,4 are key values specified in text file and i want source & destionation of these key values

Comment: Shimoon, Both input.txt & mybatchfile.bat files reside in same folder